# Git's --no-verify option

Tags: git, github, githooks

I was having an issue committing my work to GitHub (the pre-commit check was failing), so I saw in one of the fixes suggested by Git to add `--no-verify` to bypass the pre-commit check and it worked. My question is will all future pre-commits be bypassed? Or is it just a one time thing?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Just try to commit "faulty" code again and you'll see.

Comment: _... will all future pre-commits be bypassed?_ -- as long as you pass the `--no-verify` option.

Comment: Will do that, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it won't bypass any pushes or commits in the near future, unless:

1. You have an alias that adds this by default within your .gitconfig
2. You pass this flag every time you push or commit.

Regarding the second point, *you need to pass `--no-verify` every time for this to work*.

#### Option 1 Example

**.gitconfig**

Adding an alias to your git config (i.e. fcommit for force commit) would apply the `--no-verify` everytime.

```sh
[alias]
        fcommit = commit --no-verify
```

*Usage*

```
git fcommit
```